# How do I show the relationship of a class to a java.lang class in UML?

Tags: java, uml

I want to show that a class inherits from JLabel and implements MouseMotionListener in a UML diagram. What should that look like? Do I need to include all the methods they implement in the diagram?? Do I even need to show that relationship at all??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. You could simply place `JLabel` with only its classname and draw a generalization towards it. And an `«interface» MouseMotionListener` with a realization towards it. However, you can also omit that if you are not interested in such a detail level (and/or if the coder would known by heart that it's needed; I wouldn't know but I'm likely not an audience for your documenentation).

[image]

Comment: Alright thank you. I just needed something that works. I'm not sure what those relationships are just yet but I could include them.

Comment: I added a picture (sorry about the size but Retina images appear bloated here).